# Index based exact search for arbitrary character sequences in CLOB column

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

We need an exact search for arbitrary character sequences in a CLOB column. The search must be index based due to performance reasons.

At the moment we use n-grams stored in separate tables.

With Oracle Text we have learned that a tokenizer is needed. To match our "exact and character wise search" requirement this tokenizer must split our initial CLOB into single characters. No character can be ignored. Because inverted text indexes are used we doubt if this solution is appropriate.

Another option would be to leverage Lucene and Java with Oracle (supposing that Lucene supports exact character wise matching).

Are there any other options?

Comment: AFAIK Oracle Text is really only suitable for language-based searching - i.e. treating the text as a sequence of lexical units. Lucene may be a good option (haven't used it myself but heard good things about it).